# Changing back from text to image using EventListener

Tags: javascript

On my website the class ´hobby-container´ contains an image that changes to a text when i pass the mouse over.

I'm using javascript Event Listeners for that but i cannot figure how to change it back when the mouse is not over anymore

```html
<div class="hobby-container" id="hobbies-photo">
            <img src="images/hobby.png" alt="Hobbies" class="hobby">
          </div>
```

```
var hobbiesPhoto = document.getElementById("hobbies-photo");

hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  event.target.textContent = "Reading, going to the gym, traveling, listening to music, playing videogames.";
}, false);

hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
    event.target.hobbiesPhoto;
}, false);
```

I don't know which property of event.target.hobbiesPhoto use to get the image back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first save the image reference and then use innerHTML instead  hobbiesPhoto.

```
var hobbiesPhoto = document.getElementById("hobbies-photo");
var photo=`<img src="images/hobby.png" alt="Hobbies" class="hobby">`;
hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  event.target.textContent = "Reading, going to the gym, traveling, listening to music, playing videogames.";
}, false);

hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
    event.target.innerHTML = photo;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hobbiesPhoto = document.getElementById("hobbies-photo");
var imageTag = document.querySelector('.hobby');
hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  event.target.innerHTML = "Reading, going to the gym, traveling, listening to music, playing videogames.";
}, false);

hobbiesPhoto.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
    event.target.innerHTML = "";
  event.target.appendChild(imageTag);
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="hobby-container" id="hobbies-photo">
            <img src="images/hobby.png" alt="Hobbies" class="hobby">
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save JavaScript for the heavy lifting. The following demo uses CSS `:hover`

```css
.frame {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  background: none;
}

.text,
.image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  font: 700 24px/1.2 Verdana;
  text-align: center;
  top: calc(50% - 12px)
}

.image {
  top: 0;
}

.frame:hover .image,
.text {
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s
}

.image,
.frame:hover .text {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 1s
}
```

```html
<figure class="frame">
  <figcaption class='text'>Lena Söderberg</figcaption>
  <img src='https://i.ibb.co/ZHvWsKb/o1z7p.jpg' class='image'>
</figure>
```